# fread()\fscanf() reads EOF early

Tags: c, eof

While working on a programm that zips the file via Haffman tree I encountered a problem where EOF was raised way earlier than the actual end of file itself.

I have a file where data is stored like: *character (1 byte)*-*code for it (varying amount of bytes)*;

After reading 7 those combinations EOF is raised and reading stops, though there are many more of those constructions.

Code for the reading loop + initialization for dynamic arrays:

```
    char* boxarr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    int boxarrcount = 0;
    Box* text = (Box*)malloc(sizeof(Box));
    int textcount = 0;

    do {
        do {
            boxarr = (char*)realloc(boxarr, sizeof(char) * (boxarrcount + 1));
            fscanf(f, "%c", &boxarr[boxarrcount]);
            boxarrcount++;
        } while (boxarr[boxarrcount - 1] != ";"[0]);
        text[textcount].array = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (boxarrcount - 1));
        memcpy(text[textcount].array, boxarr, boxarrcount - 1);
        text[textcount].depth = boxarrcount - 1;
        textcount++;
        boxarrcount = 0;
        text = (Box*)realloc(text, sizeof(Box) * (textcount + 1));
        fread(&text[textcount].name, sizeof(char), 1, f);
    } while (fgetc(f) != EOF);

    free(boxarr);
```

Box construct if needed:

```
typedef struct Box {
    short Parent;
    short ChildL;
    short ChildR;
    unsigned char name;
    int num;
    char* array;
    int depth;
} Box;
```

A piece of file:

```
1212112211;‰-22122221;P-21112211;N-11212121;G-22212221;
-1212121;
-11211212;-1112212; -2122221;I-21222221;H-21222112;D-21221112;
```

New lines are also characters \r and \n .

Also maybe worth mentioning that it stops on the 0x1a character ().

Comment: what are the 6 that it reads?

Comment: You need to open the file in **binary** mode. Also, `do...while(fgetc(f) != EOF)` doesn't look right, you are discarding data.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Ok, will try in binary. And what do you mean by discarding data?

Comment: @user253751 A piece of file provided is its beginning. First it reads a code for the eof character used in ziping and unziping files. Then it reads 6 characters in order:  ‰, P, N, G, \r, \n and then it stops after reading 0x1a.  
That's seven actually.

Comment: Where did you pick up `";"[0]`? It sort of works, but any sober person uses `';'` instead (and ditch the [] part).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Thank a lot. The anwser was to read it in binary mode. Now it works

Comment: @Jens Didn't know about that. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Rather than `";"[0]`, you can just write `';'`.

Comment: `do { do { scanf } fread; } while( fgetc )` is a novel anti-pattern.  But it's definitely an anti-pattern.

Comment: Thanks, @WilliamPursell. 
Can you elaborate on what's an anti-pattern?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern